# too many values to unpack (expected 2)?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I got dataframe to work with and when i test/split the data this error msg pops up

too many values to unpack (expected 2)

I just set my target columns Global as y value and rest of the columns as X for train_test_split. Not sure where to start fix this issues

```
X = df[['Year_of_Release', 'Critic_Score', 'Critic_Count',
       'User_Score', 'User_Count', 'Platform_PC', 'Platform_PS3',
       'Platform_PS4', 'Platform_Wii', 'Platform_X360',
       'Platform_XOne', 'Genre_Action', 'Genre_Adventure', 'Genre_Fighting',
       'Genre_Misc', 'Genre_Platform', 'Genre_Puzzle', 'Genre_Racing',
       'Genre_Role-Playing', 'Genre_Shooter', 'Genre_Simulation',
       'Genre_Sports', 'Genre_Strategy', 'Rating_E', 'Rating_E10+', 'Rating_M',
       'Rating_RP', 'Rating_T']]

y = df[['Global']]

print(X.shape)
print(y.shape)

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X_train, X_test = train_test_split(X, y, train_size=0.8, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)


X_train, X_val = train_test_split(X_train, train_size=0.8, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

target = 'Global'
y_train = X_train[target]
y_val = X_val[target]
y_test = X_test[target]

X_train = X_train.drop(columns=target)
X_val = X_val.drop(columns=target)
X_test = X_test.drop(columns=target)

X_train.shape, y_train.shape, X_val.shape, y_val.shape, X_test.shape, y_test.shape

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-75-d3fede999d7b> in <module>()
      1 from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
      2 
----> 3 X_train, X_test = train_test_split(X, y, train_size=0.8, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)
      4 
      5 

ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
X = df[['Year_of_Release', 'Critic_Score', 'Critic_Count',
       'User_Score', 'User_Count', 'Platform_PC', 'Platform_PS3',
       'Platform_PS4', 'Platform_Wii', 'Platform_X360',
       'Platform_XOne', 'Genre_Action', 'Genre_Adventure', 'Genre_Fighting',
       'Genre_Misc', 'Genre_Platform', 'Genre_Puzzle', 'Genre_Racing',
       'Genre_Role-Playing', 'Genre_Shooter', 'Genre_Simulation',
       'Genre_Sports', 'Genre_Strategy', 'Rating_E', 'Rating_E10+', 'Rating_M',
       'Rating_RP', 'Rating_T']]

y = df[['Global']]

print(X.shape)
print(y.shape)

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)
```

Answer (score 1):

train_test_split from sklearn returns 4 values X_Train and y_train along with X_test y_test.
Refer to the official documentation [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html).

Also you should specify either of the *test size* or *train size* .